# send from first html to java script in another html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two html, first sends value to another. I want in second html receive  data in javascript. On first html page user would be able to insert localhost:8888 address, address should be send to java script in another html...for now i have default address in java script .. please help.

first html

```
<form action="second.html" method="GET" >
<input type="text" name="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

second html

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/ws");

 ws.onopen = function(evt) {
  var conn_status = document.getElementById('conn_text');
  conn_status.innerHTML = "Status: Connected!"
};

 ...
got more code 
<script>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get submitted data from URL, because your from has submit method GET:

first html:

```
<form action="second.html" method="GET" >
    <!-- In this way we can get submitted data from get param "host" -->
    <input type="text" name="host" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

second html:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // function to get params from url
    function getQueryParams(query) {
        query = query || window.location.search;
        if (query.length === 0) {
            return {};
        }

        var params = {};
        var paramsArr = query.split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < paramsArr.length; i++) {
            var p = paramsArr[i].split("=");
            params[p[0]] = p[1] || '';
        }
        return params;
    }

    // try to get param "host" from url (which submitted from first html)
    var queryParams = getQueryParams();    
    var host = queryParams.host || 'localhost:8888';

    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + '/ws');

    ws.onopen = function (evt) {
        var conn_status = document.getElementById('conn_text');
        conn_status.innerHTML = "Status: Connected!"
    };

    // more code
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain what is  var paramsArr = query.split('&');  for,  do I need it  if my query is like   http://localhost/second.html?serialNumber=127.0.0.1 how can  I use document.write() before I put new address in code

Comment: mica1234 It need if there are more than one params in URL query: http://localhost/second.html?serialNumber=127.0.0.1&a=b.

I don't understand your second question.